# Returning String[] from controller using Ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Ajax to call a method on my MVC controller. I want this to return a `string[]`. How do I achieve this in Ajax/MVC?

Do I need to convert it to a JSON object first? If so, how would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: asp.net-mvc and mvc are not the same. First one is framework, while latter one is a design-pattern.

Comment: @Leri but ASP.NET is a framework that based on MVC

Comment: @DaveJust How does it make them the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET you can write a simple controller like this:

```
public JsonResult GetStringArray()
{
    string[] d = {"a","b","d"};
    return Json(d, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then you can just call it with `http://hostname/controllerName/GetStringArray` and the output will be `["a","b","d"]`

If you want to make GET requests it's important to add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` at the end when converting.

By using a framework like jQuery you can then easily populate a drop down list.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectString"></select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://hostname/controllerName/GetStringArray", function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                $('#selectString').append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(index).html(text)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I was close! Its a Monday morning and I'm too sleepy for this :) Thanks for the quick and accurate response

Answer (score 2):

you can return JSON with whatever parameters you may need.
Create an action like the one bellow

```
public JsonResult AjaxHandler(string SomeParam)
{
    return Json(new{
            someOtherDataId = 3,
            stringArray = 
                new string[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"}
        },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```